# How to colored selected datepicker days?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a ui datepicker to booking and I want to colored my first and last selected days like below image

[image]

```js
  var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY",
    from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: 0,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      closeText: 'Temizle',
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
          document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
          //$('.checkin,#checkin,#checkout,.checkout').val('');
        }
      },
      onSelect: function(date) {
        window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
          $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find("#checkout,.checkout").focus();
        }, this), 10);
        var date2 = $('#checkin,.checkin').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
        //$('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
        $('#checkout,.checkout').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
      },
      isTo1: true,
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
      }
    });
  $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: 0,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: 'Temizle',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
        document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
        //$('.checkin,#checkin,#checkout,.checkout').val('');
      }
      var dt1 = $('#checkin,.checkin').datepicker('getDate');
      console.log(dt1);
      var dt2 = $('#checkout,.checkout').datepicker('getDate');
      if (dt2 <= dt1) {
        var minDate = $('#checkout,.checkout').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
        $('#checkout,.checkout').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
      }
    },
    isTo1: true,

    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find(".popover-wrapper").addClass("open");
    },
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
      $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
    }

  });
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> From : <input type="text" class="checkin"> To: <input type="text" class="checkout">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/awgWLR)

Answer (score 0):

You can override jquery-ui.css selector that is set to show the colors that you see to something like this for the first day.

```
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight 
{
  background: #e96e5e;
}
```

Can you add little more info about what you need to do?

Comment: I have date range as you see and if I selected a day from first datepicker my date must be colored and I have to see that day my second datepicker and if I selected a day from second datepicker it must be colored too.as you see in image thanks

Comment: I'm not certain if you need only first and last day to be in color or f.day + l.day + range(other color). Here is a link with what I think can help you [link](http://wp-hostel.com/articles/jquery-datepicker-tweaks.php)